Download RTSP video stream by loading it in canvas
I have developed one simple prototype where i do load RTSP stream into the jsmpeg canvas and then try to download the video canvas video. But when i download the video for first time then it is working but after clearing the buffer when i try to download the another video the video is not playing.
Another video's file size is 5 mb for 5 seconds video and same for first video it's also 5mb but second video is not playable while first video is being downloaded and playing perfectly.
One thing to note is when download the video i am clearing the previous buffer and in future i will not clear the buffer because in actual app once the video is downloaded i will still need the previous video buffer because in second video i will need to show the previous 5 seconds from the first video.
I tried below code which does not seems to be working but whenever i try to download the video it should download the playable video.
import { useRef } from "react";
import JSMpeg from "@cycjimmy/jsmpeg-player";

const StreamPlayer = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef<HTMLCanvasElement>(null);
  const mediaRecorderRef = useRef<MediaRecorder | null>(null);

  const blobArray = useRef<Blob[]>([]);

  const handleDownload = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    if (blobArray.current.length > 0) {
      // create file and download it

      const blob = new Blob(blobArray.current, { type: "video/webm" });
      const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      const a = document.createElement("a");
      a.href = url;
      a.download = "video.webm";
      a.click();
      window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

      blobArray.current = [];
    }
  };

  const handleDataAvailable = ({ data }: { data: Blob }) => {
    blobArray.current.push(data);
  };

  const startStream = async () => {
    new JSMpeg.Player("ws://127.0.0.1:9999", {
      canvas: videoRef.current,
      autoplay: true,
      loop: true,
    });

    if (videoRef.current !== null && videoRef.current !== undefined && videoRef.current) {
      const canvas = videoRef.current;

      const stream = canvas.captureStream(30);

      mediaRecorderRef.current = new MediaRecorder(stream, {
        mimeType: "video/webm; codecs=vp9",
      });

      mediaRecorderRef.current.addEventListener("dataavailable", (event) => {
        handleDataAvailable(event);
      });

      mediaRecorderRef.current.start(1000);

      mediaRecorderRef.current.addEventListener("error", (event) => {
        console.error("Error", event);
      });
    } else {
      console.error("Canvas element is null in the ref");
    }
  };

  setTimeout(() => {
    startStream();
  }, 1000);

  return (
    <div>
      <canvas ref={videoRef} />

      <button onClick={handleDownload}>Download</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default StreamPlayer;


Could be that the frirst include iframe/PPS/SPS and when you Download the Second time you start from a non iframe Position what cant be Played.
